# Is there an easy way to give a card in a list a set of points?

Tags: python, python-3.x, blackjack, playing-cards

My assignment was to create a very simple version of Blackjack in python, where you ask if they want to play, they say yes and it draws a card, it says the number of points that you now have after you've picked the card and then ask if you want to play again. I need help with implementing the "points system".

I tried doing some if statements where if a number was in the list it would give it the same amount of points that it is, but I found out that it didn't work.

```
import random

nummer = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Kung", "Dam", 
"Knekt", "Ess"]
kort = ["♦", "♥", "♣", "♠"]
kortlek = []
for n in range(0, 4):
    for x in range(0, 13):
        kortlek.append(kort[n] + " " + nummer[x])

d_k = []

svar = input("Do you want to play? (y/n) ")

if svar == "y":
    drag = random.choice(kortlek)
    print("You got ", drag)
    d_k.append(drag)
    kortlek.remove(drag)
else:
    print("Bye")
```

Basically I want it so that after you've drawn a card it tells the amount of points you have in total.

Comment: Create a second array `points` holding the points for each card (2, 3, ..., ace), then `zip` those with `nummer` in your `kortlek` loop, and make each card a tuple `(name, points)`

Comment: Instead of `nummer` being a list of `['2', '3'...]`, make it a dictionary of `{'2':2, '3':3...}`. That will allow you to look up the value of each card. This will also help you improve the loop that creates the deck, by looping over the `nummer` dictionary and `kort` list themselves rather than looping over their indices.

Comment: Never use strings to represent data, unless that data is actual written text (which cards are not). Use numbers to represent cards, and just convert to strings for output.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comment by @TigerhawkT3, making `kortlek` a dictionary with each card having it's card value will do.

```
import random

nummer = ["Ess", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Knekt", "Dam", 
"Kung"] # Kung = king, dam = queen, knekt = jack, ess = ace (assumed)
kort = ["♦", "♥", "♣", "♠"]
kortlek = {} # (Card choice : Value) using dictionary
for n in range(0, 4): # Can remove "0, "
    for x in range(0, 13): # Can remove "0, "
        kortlek[kort[n] + " " + nummer[x]] = x + 1

d_k = []

svar = input("Do you want to play? (y/n) ")

if svar == "y":
    drag = random.choice(list(kortlek.keys()))
    print("You got ", drag, "which has a card value of:", kortlek[drag])
    d_k.append(drag)
    del kortlek[drag]
else:
    print("Bye")
```

You can beautify output and format it yourself and continue from here. Good luck! :)

**EDIT**: Also be aware that in a blackjack game, Ace ("Ess") can be either 1 or 11. I didn't help you code it, but you should be able to implement that using a `if` loop :)

[Test it Yourself](https://repl.it/repls/CarefulRedundantFact)

Comment: You've kept `nummer` as a list and turned the deck (`kortlek`) into a dictionary. The loops also haven't been cleaned up, you don't account for ace being 1 or 11, etc.

Comment: Yes but I hope you can figure it out :) If you can't, feel free to post another question / comment here and I can help you further

Comment: @GarethMa I don't really like asking for help, but I'm new to python and coding in general, would you like to show me how to implement the ace function? If you'd want to we could talk over discord or something tomorrow, I'm free all day, if not it's okay, but I'd really appreciate some help :)

Comment: Yes sure, would you like to start a discord server and post the link here?